# Django M2M CreateView and UpdateView from related model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, many-to-many

I've got these models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=ugettext_lazy(u'Name'))
    building = models.ForeignKey(Building, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=ugettext_lazy(u'Building'))
    parking_spaces_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name=ugettext_lazy(u'Parking spaces count'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)


class Car(models.Model):
    registration_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name=ugettext_lazy(u'Registration number'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.registration_number)


class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=(ugettext_lazy(u'First name')))
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=(ugettext_lazy(u'Last name')))
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=(ugettext_lazy(u'Identification card number')))
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=ugettext_lazy(u'Company'), related_name='employees')
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car, verbose_name=ugettext_lazy(u'Cars'), related_name='owners')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(' '.join([self.first_name, self.last_name]))
```

and I'd like to be able to implement:

1 - CarCreateView - where I would create a Car object in my database by supplying its registration_number and owners (which is a related field from Employee model) fields. When I try putting 'owners' in fields like that (using Django's CreateView):

```
fields = ('registration_number', 'owners')
```

I get an error "Unknown field(s) (owners) specified for Car".

I managed to simulate it with FormView which works:

```
class CarCreateView(FormView):
    model = Car
    template_name = 'companies/cars/add.html'
    form_class = CarCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('companies:cars:list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        employees = form.cleaned_data['owners']
        registration_number = form.cleaned_data['registration_number']
        car = Car(registration_number=registration_number)
        car.save()
        car.owners = employees
        return super(CarCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My question here is - is this DRY or could it be better?

2 - CarEditView - where I would be able to edit an existing object of a car by supplying its registration_number and owners. So far I've tried using FormView but I did not achieve anything so could you please guide me what to do? It'd be best if I could just use UpdateView but I guess it's not that simple with M2M relation.

Daniel